# Angular + ngfire 2 , variable declared in constructor not assigned correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, observable

In constructor, I declared `this.lcId` variable the console log above that displays correct value. But in another component I created an object from that and called this `requestedBulbCount` method. Then I found that second console log (which starts with bulb count service) does not display the value which I declared in the constructor. How to solve this?

I am no that much familiar with Angular and Firebase so I would be much thankful to you if you could supply an in-depth answer

[image]

```
export class StatusService {
  private requestCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<reqest>;
  request: Observable<reqest[]>;
  localUser1: Observable<reqest[]>;
  private lcId:string =  '';

  constructor(private afs:AngularFirestore , private localGov: LocalGovService) {    
    this.localGov.getLocalGoverment().subscribe(  async (a)=>{
      console.log('localGov service :- ' + a[0].lcId)  
      this.lcId = await  a[0].lcId   
  })
     }


  requestedBulbCount(){      
    console.log('Bulb count service  ' + this.lcId)
    this.requestCollection = this.afs.collection<reqest>('bulbRequests', ref =>
     ref.where('status' , '==' , 'incomplete').where('lcId','==',this.lcId));
    this.request = this.requestCollection.valueChanges(); 
    this.requestCollection.get().subscribe()
    return this.request  
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your code as text instead of image? Thanks!

Comment: @norbitrial code supplied along with image